Getting rid of "CHAPTER" in the header
I can't seem to get rid of it saying "Chapter" in the header. I asked my LLM a dozen times, I even tried yelling at it.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, inner=1in, outer=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\bfseries\Large}{\thechapter.}{0.5em}{}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{Book Title}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{This is an example footnote for the introduction.}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[2-4]\footnote{This is an example footnote for the first chapter.}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[5-7]\footnote{This is an example footnote for the second chapter.}

\backmatter

\chapter*{Notes}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notes}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}

\section*{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[1] This is an example footnote for the introduction.
\end{itemize}

\section*{First Chapter}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[1] This is an example footnote for the first chapter.
\end{itemize}

\section*{Second Chapter}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[1] This is an example footnote for the second chapter.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}



Sorry, but LLMs are not suitable to give validated answers. Better read package manuals, e.g., the fancyhdr user manual (figure 3 there IMHO already answers your question).

It seems, what you are searching is almost the default of KOMA-Script class scrbook:
\documentclass[12pt,sfdefaults=false,numbers=withenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, inner=1in, outer=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pagestyleset=standard,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{}% add page number to the footer of plain pages

\usepackage{chapterbib}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\large}% reduce size of chapter headings
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}% (remove slanted from) font of page header and footer

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{Book Title}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{This is an example footnote for the introduction.}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[2-4]\footnote{This is an example footnote for the first chapter.}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[5-7]\footnote{This is an example footnote for the second chapter.}

\backmatter

\chapter{Notes}% after \backmatter chapters are not numbered

\section*{Introduction}% you can alternatively use \addsec{Introduction} to have the sections in the ToC
\begin{itemize}
  \item[1] This is an example footnote for the introduction.
\end{itemize}

\section{First Chapter}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[1] This is an example footnote for the first chapter.
\end{itemize}

\section*{Second Chapter}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[1] This is an example footnote for the second chapter.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


To keep your code, you can alternatively redefine \chaptermark:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not needed for more than a decade
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, inner=1in, outer=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\bfseries\Large}{\thechapter.}{0.5em}{}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter. #1}}{}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{Book Title}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{This is an example footnote for the introduction.}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[2-4]\footnote{This is an example footnote for the first chapter.}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[5-7]\footnote{This is an example footnote for the second chapter.}

\backmatter

\chapter*{Notes}% you can alternativly use \chapter{Notes} …
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notes}% … and then would not need this.
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}

\section*{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[1] This is an example footnote for the introduction.
\end{itemize}

\section*{First Chapter}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[1] This is an example footnote for the first chapter.
\end{itemize}

\section*{Second Chapter}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[1] This is an example footnote for the second chapter.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}

